# Not hacking CurlException: 60 (cURL SSL Certificate Verification)

Tags: php, ssl, curl, certificate, verify

The error that alot of people get with Facebook authentication is:

```
CurlException: 60: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

And the only information I can find about it suggest to add the following lines of code to curl:

```
$opts[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = false;
$opts[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST] = 2;
```

I know this works, but what is going on here?
Isn't there any server settings/configuraton that can be changed instead of hacking up facebook.php.

Comment: Whose certificate is getting verified here?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### What It Does & Meaning:

The following code tells the cURL to NOT verify that security certificates are correct. Hence, the error disappears.

```
  $opts[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = false;
  $opts[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST] = 2;
```

When you connect to a remote server with SSL, their certificate might be invalid, expired, or not signed by a recognized CA. The cURL normally checks it.

**CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST:**

- 1: to check the existence of a common name in the SSL peer certificate.
- 2: to check the existence of a common name and also verify that it matches the hostname provided.

**CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER:** FALSE to stop CURL from verifying the peer's certificate. Alternate certificates to verify against can be specified with the CURLOPT_CAINFO option or a certificate directory can be specified with the `CURLOPT_CAPATH` option. CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST may also need to be TRUE or FALSE if CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER is disabled (it defaults to 2).

---

### How to Enable & Verify Correctly:

To verify correctly, we need to to verify the certificate being presented to us is good for real. We do this by comparing it against a certificate we reasonable* trust.

If the remote resource is protected by a certificate issued by one of the main CA's like Verisign, GeoTrust et al, you can safely compare against Mozilla's CA certificate bundle which you can get from http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html

Save the file cacert.pem somewhere in your server and set the following options in your script.

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TRUE); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "pathto/cacert.pem");
```

If you are connecting to a resource protected by a self-signed certificate, all you need to do is obtain a copy of the certificate in PEM format and append it to the cacert.pem of the above paragraph.

Comment: I think his main question is what to do to get around this hack.

Comment: so what would be the reason that this only happens on one of my servers and not the other?

Comment: @John, other servers have in-built security certificates and do not need specifying certificates manually. Just like the browsers IE/Firefox have certificates in-built and does not require by YOU to give a cert file everytime you want to connect to a secure login site like GMAil, HoTMaiL.

Comment: the variable $ch, where is it defined?

Comment: Ah! I've been looking everywhere for this relating to using a self signed certificate for nuSOAP.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I could not use curl_setopt, because I could not edit Facebook API classes ( conditions of project I was working in ).

I solved the problem by adding path to cacert.pem downloaded from http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html to my php.ini

```
[curl]
curl.cainfo = "c:\wamp\cacert.pem"
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem, and disabling peer verification is not acceptable in my case.
I updated the fa_ca_chain_bundle.crt file (from [facebook's gitbub](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/tree/master/src)) and it works now.

Regards,
Marek